# Displaying menu items?

Tags: views

I am trying to create a view by pulling in a secondary menu I created. How do I do this?

I would like 8 items displayed over two columns (which means 4 items in each column) on the homepage.

Comment: This question is unlikely to help any future visitors; it is only relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet. For help making this question more broadly applicable, see the FAQ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use menus/menu items in Views (yet), but it sounds like you want some kind of [megamenu](http://www.uie.com/articles/mega_menus/) solution.

[Megamenu](http://drupal.org/project/megamenu), [OM Maximenu](http://drupal.org/project/om_maximenu) and [Superfish](http://drupal.org/project/superfish) are all good solutions for this.